# Why matplotlib slider not working in Colab?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've stuck with an issue that I have a slider but It's not interactive, I followed by documentation but even ready solution didn't worked, how to solve that? Not worked in Google Colab and Jupyter Notebook.
I have already tried to change matplotlib backend kernel from qt to ktinker but nothing

my code :

```
%matplotlib inline
!pip install --upgrade matplotlib

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button


# The parametrized function to be plotted
def reliability_graph (t,mu_,lambda_):
  return (mu_/(lambda_+mu_))+(lambda_/(lambda_+mu_))*np.exp(-(lambda_+mu_)*t)

t = np.linspace(0, 10,1000)

# Define initial parameters
init_mu = 0
init_lambda = 0.1

# Create the figure and the line that we will manipulate
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = plt.plot(t, reliability_graph (t,init_mu,init_lambda), lw=2)
ax.set_xlabel('Relibility')

# adjust the main plot to make room for the sliders
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)

# Make a horizontal slider to control the frequency.
axmu = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
mu_slider = Slider(
    ax=axmu,
    label='Mu',
    valmin=0,
    valmax=1,
    valinit=init_mu,
)

# Make a vertically oriented slider to control the amplitude
axlambda = plt.axes([0.1, 0.25, 0.0225, 0.63])
lambda_slider = Slider(
    ax=axlambda,
    label="Lambda",
    valmin=0,
    valmax=1,
    valinit=init_lambda,
    orientation="vertical"
)


# The function to be called anytime a slider's value changes
def update(val):
    line.set_ydata(reliability_graph(t, mu_slider.val, lambda_slider.val))
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()


# register the update function with each slider
mu_slider.on_changed(update)
lambda_slider.on_changed(update)

# Create a `matplotlib.widgets.Button` to reset the sliders to initial values.
resetax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', hovercolor='0.975')


def reset(event):
    mu_slider.reset()
    lambda_slider.reset()
button.on_clicked(reset)

plt.show()
```

My aim is to get a graph with working sliders ,so that I can change values of my parameters interactively. The problem is that sliders aren’t works, they appears as a picture not an interactive object

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used sliders or buttons in Colab, but by running your code and introducing the two-point library from the error message, the graph and slider buttons are now enabled.

```
#!pip install ipympl
#from google.colab import output
#output.enable_custom_widget_manager()

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button
%matplotlib widget

def reliability_graph (t,mu_,lambda_):
  return (mu_/(lambda_+mu_))+(lambda_/(lambda_+mu_))*np.exp(-(lambda_+mu_)*t)

t = np.linspace(0, 10,1000)

# Define initial parameters
init_mu = 0
init_lambda = 0.1

# Create the figure and the line that we will manipulate
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = plt.plot(t, reliability_graph (t,init_mu,init_lambda), lw=2)
ax.set_xlabel('Relibility')

# adjust the main plot to make room for the sliders
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)

# Make a horizontal slider to control the frequency.
axmu = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
mu_slider = Slider(
    ax=axmu,
    label='Mu',
    valmin=0,
    valmax=1,
    valinit=init_mu,
)

# Make a vertically oriented slider to control the amplitude
axlambda = plt.axes([0.1, 0.25, 0.0225, 0.63])
lambda_slider = Slider(
    ax=axlambda,
    label="Lambda",
    valmin=0,
    valmax=1,
    valinit=init_lambda,
    orientation="vertical"
)


# The function to be called anytime a slider's value changes
def update(val):
    line.set_ydata(reliability_graph(t, mu_slider.val, lambda_slider.val))
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()


# register the update function with each slider
mu_slider.on_changed(update)
lambda_slider.on_changed(update)

# Create a `matplotlib.widgets.Button` to reset the sliders to initial values.
resetax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', hovercolor='0.975')


def reset(event):
    mu_slider.reset()
    lambda_slider.reset()

button.on_clicked(reset)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: When I press the link Colab above and run the notebook I get an error in the second cell at line 23.... Has something changed in colab since this was posted? Or some other error? Very interested to get this to work.

Comment: @janpeter The first three lines are commented out, but can be executed by uncommenting them. I removed the link in the comment. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I copied the file in your example and run it in my own Google Drive / Colab. And included the three first lines as you said. Still does not work... looks like something simple though. Error at line 20 : fig, ax = plt.subplots()

Comment: Did you install correctly by executing the first three lines? Do you see an error statement, but the following on the last line? `Successfully installed fonttools-4.33.3 ipympl-0.9.1 matplotlib-3.5.2`

Comment: I execute the first three lines. But do not get "Successfully....", still no error message here. Seems hard to add a screenshot here.

Comment: Divided the code in some pieces and now work! But here is some considerable lag, between adjusting the slider and see the result. Far from running it all locally....

Comment: @janpeter My understanding is that local is faster because there is no communication. I have not actually run it in a local environment.