# Update Time Series date range in Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, panel

As you can see in the last cell when you change the date slider and click on Update everything works but I duplicate the Figure everytime underneath the panel. I am new to Python and Colab so I am stuck I need some help thanks :)
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11SWIbkbOVonXWtEQnA6C_ns1Ij0RZh43?usp=sharing

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71280223/why-matplotlib-slider-not-working-in-colab

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple demonstration of the solution:

```
import ipywidgets
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

output = ipywidgets.Output()

def plo_fct(w=1):
    with output:
        clear_output(wait=True)  # Clear output area
        x = np.random.uniform(0, 5, size=100)
        y = 2 * x + w * np.random.normal(size=100)
        plt.scatter(x, y)
        plt.show()
        

# Create a button and callback function
button = ipywidgets.Button(description="Update Plot")
def on_button_click(button):
    plo_fct(w=slider.value)

# Create a slider
slider = ipywidgets.FloatSlider(value=1, min=0, max=5, step=0.5, description='w')

# Display the button, slider, and output widget
display(button)
display(slider)
display(output)

# Connect the button to the callback function
button.on_click(on_button_click)
```